# Index and length must refer to a location within the string." & vbCrLf & "Parameter name: length vb.net

Tags: vb.net, substring

```
Public Sub Main(temp As String)
    Dim AccNo As String = temp.Substring(0, 18)
    Dim Identifier As String = temp.Substring(36, 46)
    Dim Expected As String = temp.Substring(45, 98)
    Dim Received As String = temp.Substring(100, 105)
    Dim Length As String = temp.Length.ToString
    lbLength.Text = Length.ToString

    lbAcc.Text = AccNo.ToString
    lbIdentifier.Text = Identifier.ToString
    lbExpected.Text = Expected.ToString
    lbReceived.Text = Received.ToString
End Sub
```

[image]

I'm trying to extract a section from a String line. It's working correctly first two times but then it generates

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string." & vbCrLf & "Parameter name: length vb.net"

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Remember, the second parameter for Substring is not the ending position, but the number of characters to retrieve starting from the first parameter

Comment: You can use the Mid() function in VB.NET, Substring() doesn't work the same way.

Comment: @HansPassant : Don't encourage him to use functions from the VB6 era. :)

Comment: Why do you assume he can't write that function himself?  It is a very simple one.  Btw, I stopped commenting on your posts after you asked me to, I'll ask for the favor in return.

Comment: thank you Stave and Hans

Comment: @HansPassant : What? I've never asked you to stop commenting on my posts?? What are you talking about?

Comment: @HansPassant : I don't intend to nag, but _if_ you were talking to me in your previous comment I really have no idea what you're referring to as I can't recall that I would've asked you to stop commenting :(. Your knowledge and comments are very valuable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of your Sub check the length of the temp string.

```
Dim temp As String = ""
    If temp.Length < 205 Then
        MessageBox.Show("String is too short to process")
        Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Substring(StartPosition,length) length is number of characters from starting position.

If you want to do it like Substring(start_position,end_position) end position has to be replaced with (98-45), because end-start=length

Comment: Thank you very much. but i cannot understand why its not affect on to this "  Dim Identifier As String = temp.Substring(36, 46)" that work properly

Comment: I can not say because I do not know what temp is. Breakpoint the code or put debug.print(temp.length) above.

Comment: 36+46=82 so string is at least that long, 45+98=143 but is shorter than 143. if you comment the second substring, I bet you would get the same error on the third as 100+105=205 that is even longer.